# How can I list the maximum per key, value in RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have an RDD like this

```
[(101372, ('Drama', 250)),
(10123, ('Western', 250)),
(101372, ('Western', 200)),
(10123, ('Drama', 200)),
]
```

I wish to transform it into

```
  [(101372, ('Drama', 250)),
    (10123, ('Western', 250)),]
```

I require to calculate the maximum of each x[1][1] for each USERID and
this piece of code I have tried so far only returns the maximum of all keys

```
userCountGenres.max(lambda x : x[1][1])
```

What code do I need to get the maximum for each RDD key?

I'm working with jupyter notebooks and pyspark

Answer (score 1):

You are already having a pair RDD, so it should be easy to accomplish that `max` calculation using a reduce by key operation:

```
userCountGenres.reduceByKey(lambda v1,v2 : v1 if v1[1] > v2[1] else v2)
```

This essentially does the same `max` calculation (because the function used just selects the tuple with the highest number), but this is done per key (Spark does the grouping).